# How to add and subtract user input in alternating order in c++

Tags: c++, loops, integer

I'm supposed to test if a number is divisible by 11 or not.
I know it takes one line code to check if the number is divisible by 11 or not by using `if (input % 11 == 0)` But I am supposed to write an algorithm that finds out the divisibility by adding and subtracting the number in an alternating order and then checks if the result is divisible by 11 or not.
For example, the number 1364, the program would do: `1 - 3 + 6 - 4` which is 0 and it's basically divisible by 11.

This is my current algorithm, I know it's a bit incoherent, I'm working on that. It's supposed to add and subtract the user input in alternating order and then check if the sum is divisible by 11 or not.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getInput(){
int input;
cout << "Enter the number" << "\n";
cin >> input;
return input;
}


int For11(int x){
 if (to_string(x).length() > 1 && to_string(x).length() < 11){ //Range
  //string num = to_string(x);
  for (int i = 1; i % 11 != 0; i++){
    int sum = i + i - i + i; // The heart of the algorithm
    cout << sum << "\n";
    if (sum % 11 == 0){
     // some code goes here;
return 0;}
    else {
    // some code goes here;
return 1;}

  }
 }
}


int main() {
For11(getInput());
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it.

The biggest problem is this part right here:

```
int sum = i + i - i + i;
```

Suppose `i` is `0`. What would that look like:

```
0 + 0 - 0 + 0
```

That is of course `0`.

Now suppose `i` is `1`:

```
1 + 1 - 1 + 1
```

That is equal to 2.

If you keep going, it is easy to see that sum always equals `2 * i`. That isn't what you want at all.

What you want is to add some number to a running total based on the value of `i`:

```
int sum = to_int(to_string(x)[0]); // to_int would be some function to convert an
                                   // char to an integer it is not necessarily a 
                                   // standard function. I'll leave that part for
                                   // you to figure out
for(int i = 1; i % 11 != 0; i++) {
    if(i%2 == 0) {
        sum += to_int(to_string(x)[i]);
    } else {
        sum -= to_int(to_string(x)[i]);
    }
}
//...
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to convert any number given by the user into the digits that compound this number. If the user input is: "123456" you want to catch as integer variables this output: {1,2,3,4,5,6} and then operate with this into your algorithm. For that case my suggestion is to use `std::string` and then you can do a casting to `(int)` for each character of the strings. I propose the next code, but notice that it is not designed to detect if the user inputs other character than numbers. Notice also that to do the casting I subtract 48 to the char code because it is the correspondency with ASCII.

edit: I don't know if it will help you because your question was vague at some point, but at least it was funny to do for me.

`#include <iostream>`

`#include <string>`

`#include <vector>`

`int signFun(int i) {`

```
int sign{-1};

if (i % 2== 0) return 1;
else return -1;
```

`}`

`int main() {`

```
std::string userInputNum;
std::cout << "Introduce a number" << std::endl;
std::cin >> userInputNum;

std::vector<int> digits(userInputNum.length());
int sumDigits{0};

  for (unsigned i=0; i<userInputNum.length(); ++i) {

    digits[i] = (int)(userInputNum.at(i)-48);
    sumDigits += signFun(i)*digits[i];
}

    std::cout << sumDigits << std::endl;
```

`}`

Comment: Hey, I just edited my question for better understanding.

Comment: Don't use variable length arrays - use `std::vector`.

Comment: @iz_ I've changed this by following your advice but, could you explain this a little bit? Is the reason because of compiler doesn't know the size of the array in compiler time and then this size, even when is supposed to be stack-allocated, is totally dependent on user input and hence totally unpredictable?

Comment: The reason is very simple: VLAs are non-standard in C++. They are implemented as an extension in come compilers, like GCC.

Comment: Am Ok I didn't notice since I've been always programming with gcc in Linux. Thanks!